# How to blur a single layer in a grease pencil object?

Tags: grease-pencil, layers

I was wondering, is it possible to blur a single layer in a grease pencil object like, for example, the gaussian blur in Photoshop ? I know there is a "blur" effect in the visual effects properties but it is applied to the entire object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can but you can approach it by using a combination of modifiers, which support layers.

Let's say you have two strokes created with the same material but on two different layers :

[image]

Add a *Thickness* modifier, in the influence set it to your target layer

[image]

Add an *Opacity* modifier, set the layer. Set the mode to *Hardness* and decrease it.

[image]

Add another *Opacity* modifier, set the layer again. Decrease the strength or the factor.

[image]

You might want to disable or enable *Self Overlap* on the material if you want to decrease the artifacts.

[image]

The artifacts are particularly prominent on sharp turns.

[image]